# python unittesting -- how to get more explicit coverage info

Tags: code-coverage, python-unittest

I'm using `py.test` together with `coverage` to generate coverage information, so that i can see how much of my code i've written unittests for.

```
coverage run --source=package_directory/sources -m py.test package_directory/tests
coverage report -m --include=package_directory
coverage html --include=package_directory
```

the coverage generates nice and fine and actually works as i'd hope it to do(when i make a new unittest to test a specific function and run the commands mentioned before, that function goes from "missing" to "run", as supposed to). The thing is though, there is coverage showing up in scripts that i haven't even touched yet, which makes me think that my unittests aren't completely isolated and somewhere are spilling over into other functions. I'd like to use `coverage` to see where this happens.

So, the basic question comes down to this:
**If a statement (function) is marked as "run" in coverage report, is there a way to see from where it is run (called)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not yet a way to track covered lines back to the tests that execute them.  Keep in mind that simply importing a module will execute the top-level statements in the module (typically `def` and `class` definitions).

Comment: Well, is this type of functionality in the works? 
Would it even be possible? Taking into account how python can track through all of the functions down to the exception when it is thrown?
Would it even benefit anyone besides me?

Comment: This is a common request.  Many people want it.  The challenge is two-fold: collecting all the data (now for each line, instead of run/not-run, we need to store a list of test names), and then, how to present that information?